# Rebase branch containing a (non-fast-forward) merge

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a topic branch (*new-http-api*) in git which is based on a master branch (*v0.98-series*) that had some stuff integrated.

Now I wanted to rebase my topic branch to get the newly integrated stuff using `git rebase v0.98-series`. However, this fails with conflicts completely unrelated to the new things. These conflicts occur at a position where I performed a merge with another branch.

I'm now looking for a way to fix this. Losing parts of the history wouldn't be a problem.

The commit history looks like that:

```
* 163e527 - (HEAD, pub/new-http-api, priv/new-http-api, new-http-api) [FIX] Monkeypatch icalendar to fix rrules in iCal (26 minutes ago) <MYSELF>
* 9392d22 - [IMP] Add iCal export for reservations (87 minutes ago) <MYSELF>
.......................................
* f0af4bb - [REF] Use tuple instead of list for '... in (...)' (7 days ago) <MYSELF>
* b7d5e36 - [IMP] Use HTTP 400 response if limit is too high (7 days ago) <MYSELF>
*   d3a7b57 - [VER] Merge pedro's sorting/limit changes (7 days ago) <MYSELF>
|\
| * a18690b - [IMP] HTTP API - sorting (8 days ago) <SOMEONE_ELSE>
* | ebbe2ca - [REF] Store statuscode in HTTPAPIError exception (7 days ago) <MYSELF>
* | de43588 - [IMP] Improve accesskey/signature and cache system (7 days ago) <MYSELF>
* | f2d6a0a - [IMP] Require HTTPS for authenticated requests (8 days ago) <MYSELF>
* | 69d733f - [IMP] Add request signature validation (8 days ago) <MYSELF>
* | 29e6755 - [FIX] Ignore unknown kwargs in Serializer (8 days ago) <MYSELF>
|/
* db99b6f - [REF] Improve export routing and error handling (8 days ago) <MYSELF>
* 0ad22e1 - [FIX] return proper results (again) (8 days ago) <MYSELF>
......................
* 4846eb3 - [IMP] Fairly functional API version (4 weeks ago) <SOMEONE_ELSE>
* 08ea247 - [FTR] HTTP API - First sketch (4 weeks ago) <SOMEONE_ELSE>
```

`git merge v0.98-series` would work fine, but I'd highly prefer to rebase that topic branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer version of git allow cherry-picking a range of commits (essentially a rebase). You can pick off the commit ranges before, between, and after the merge onto the head of master.

Comment: Will this also allow me to pick the merge commit (i.e. the one fixing the ugly conflicts)?

Comment: Once you have the commits on HEAD you can always do a 'rebase -i' and squash commits down.

Comment: So I guess i won't have a chance but doing the ugly conflict fixes I did during the merge again?

Comment: I don't believe that's necessary. If I'm reading your tree right, cherry-pick 08ea247^..ebbe2ca then cherry-pick d3a7b57..163e527. Essentially were applying each of the commits as patches on top of a different HEAD. The merge/fixup commit is not included.

Comment: Thanks that helped. However, i had to `git cherry-pick d3a7b57 -m 1` the merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the git rebase --preserve-merges option.

Comment: Failed: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/391267/ - and the conflicts are horrible to merge (huge block of code changed, when doing the merge some time ago I actually took my code and applied the changes from the other guy manually)

Comment: It doesn't guarantee no conflicts, but it does mean that you can keep the inner merge.  If you have legitimate conflicts, you can't make them go away.

Comment: I don't think my answer is going to help, but it was worth a shot :(

Comment: Well the conflicts were fixed in the merge commit. They are completely unrelated to the changes "introduced" by the rebase - the conflicted files don't even exist in the master branch.